# How to create a select with username from a database with laravel and keep in use the Form Class

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to insert  dynamically because it's from my database and i don't know to do it with the Form class of laravel,

```
$select = Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S');
```

is there something like a method to insert data after created ?
like

```
$select->option('far' => 'boo');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that - because `Form::select` returns a string. i.e. your `$select` is just a string, not an object

What you could do is this:

```
$select_array = array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small');
```

then later on do this dynamically

```
$select_array['M'] = 'Medium';
```

then when you are ready to output the actual display:

```
Form::select('size', $select_array, 'S');
```